# Finding the local extrema of $(1-x^2)/x^3$ without using calculus or a computer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

I am a student learning precalculus, and I have to solve the problem: find the local extrema of $\frac{1-x^2}{x^3}$.
It is easy using a calculator or applying calculus, but I have no idea how to solve it without them, which is the way that our school is wanting.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Simplify to (1/x^3)-(1/x)

Comment: Subtract the maximum value, the difference has a squared factor times a negative factor, so the max of the difference is 0

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280650/finding-local-extrema-of-a-certain-rational-function-without-calculus. In fact, the value for the local max and min are the same for your question, $\pm \sqrt{3}$. I believe that post should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. As an odd function, it is enough to study for $x>0$.
2. By AM-GM, $\dfrac1{x^3}+k^3+k^3 \geqslant  3k^2\dfrac1{x}$, now can you see what value of $k$ to select to get the minimum of $\dfrac1{x^3}-\dfrac1x$?